# Execution failed for task ':react-native-geocoder:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: react-native

[image]Hi I am trying create release apk , here I have used react-native-geocode, but while creating build getting bellow error

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-geocoder:verifyReleaseResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Do anyone faced such issue ??

Comment: show full error log

Comment: @ Rutvik Bhatt added log image

Comment: Do you use `fontSize`, `colorError` in android styles.xml or in some xml file?

Comment: @ Rutvik Bhatt No I am using is js file itself like  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  form: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },

  button: {
    marginTop: 15,
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
    padding: 12,
    borderRadius: 20
  },
  feedbackMessage: {
    width: 350,
    alignItems: "center",
  }
});

Comment: open `android/gradle.properties` file and add `android.enableAapt2=false` hope it works

Comment: @Rutvik Bhatt "android.enableAapt2=false" Not working

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19239#issuecomment-390225700) solution

Comment: @ Rutvik Bhatt believe me I have tried this as well :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183706/discussion-between-vishal-pachpande-and-rutvik-bhatt).

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2):

Hi try this android/build.gradle At end add:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, with a similar problem. Thank you for the solution! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hi add this in android/build.gradle At end add:

```
subprojects {
afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
            buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).